# How to set `vmin` and `vmax` for Holoviews Images?

Tags: matplotlib, holoviews

I'm using GeoViews to plot maps of gridded data, as `gv.Image` object.  Currently, my plotting function looks like this:

```
def plot_variable(path):
    var_ = xr.open_dataarray(path)
    dataset = gv.Dataset(var_[:, 0].to_dataset(),
                     kdims=kdims, vdims=vdims)

    pl_ = hv.Overlay([
              dataset.to(gv.Image, geo_dims, crs=prj_)(
                      plot=dict(projection=prj_, vmax=0.04)),
              gf.coastline(plot=dict(projection=prj_, scale='10m'),
                           style=dict(linewidth=2.5)),
              gf.borders(plot=dict(projection=prj_, scale='10m'),
                   style=dict(linewidth=1.5)),
              ]).collate()

    return pl_
```

Now, I would like to set the minima and maxima of the color's range, i.e., the HoloViews equivalent of the `vmin` and `vmax` kwargs.

**How can I set `vmin` and `vmax` when using `gv.Image`?**

Answer (score 4):

@eudoxos: You could use the **clim** parameter in the **.opts** options like

```
 import holviews as hv
 vmin=0
 vmax=0.4
 hv.Image(np.random.randn(4, 5)).opts(cmap='gray',clim=(vmin,vmax))
```

[Output of above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sATnq.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the range of the value dimension of the image:

```
import holoviews as hv
img = hv.Image(np.random.randn(4, 5))
img.redim(z=dict(range=(-10, 10)))
```

Comment: Is there no way to specify `vmin` / `vmax` in hv.Image directly via options?